# Function that change pages on click dosent work with no reason

Tags: javascript, function

So I tried to make a function similar to one from w3schools. The function needs to manage 2 things. 1. To add the ".active" class to a dot when the current page is called. 2.When the user clicks on dot to go to that page.

In my code, if I let some space when adding a class through function Example(dots[sliderIndex].classList.add(" active");) now it works to click and go on that page but if I cut the space (dots[sliderIndex].classList.add("active");) now shows the active state but clicking on dots not working. It confuses me so much...Please, guys if you can explain to me the logic behind and how to make this work

```js
// *Second Slider*
var sliderIndex = 0;
let next2 = document.querySelector(".next2");
let prev2 = document.querySelector(".prev2");

function showNews(n) {
  debugger;
  const slider = document.getElementsByClassName("news");
  const dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slider.length; i++) {
    slider[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  if (n < 0) {
    sliderIndex = slider.length - 1;
  }
  if (n > slider.length - 1) {
    sliderIndex = 0;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", " ");
  }
  slider[sliderIndex].style.display = "block";
  dots[sliderIndex].classList.add(" active");
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showNews((sliderIndex = n));
}

function incrementSlides2(n) {
  showNews((sliderIndex += n));
}

next2.addEventListener("click", function() {
  incrementSlides2(1);
});

prev2.addEventListener("click", function() {
  incrementSlides2(-1);
});

showNews(sliderIndex);
```

```css
#section-three .slideshow-container2 .wiew-more:hover {
  color: #242121;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 #dots {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .dot:hover,
#section-three .slideshow-container2 .dot.active {
  background: black;
}

.active {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<section id="section-three">
  <div class="container slideshow-container2">
    <div class="news">
      <div class="news-content">
        <div class="buttons">
          <a class="btn company-btn" href="#">COMPANY NEWS</a>
          <a class="btn industry-btn" href="#">INDUSTRY NEWS</a>
        </div>
        <h1>OUR PEOPLE ARE OUT STONGEST ASSET </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="news news2">
      <div class="news2-content">
        <div class="buttons">
          <a class="btn company-btn" href="#">COMPANY NEWS</a>
          <a class="btn industry-btn" href="#">INDUSTRY NEWS</a>
        </div>
        <h1 class="media-room">MEDIA ROOM </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="dots">
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="prev2"></a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="next2"></a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Please fix the _"InvalidCharacterError: String contains an invalid character"_ error

Comment: start by removing the space in front of `active` here `dots[sliderIndex].classList.add(" active")` as spaces in class-names aren't allowed..

Comment: @Andreas i don't know how it says that the error is at line 96 and i dont have a clue what s the error

Comment: @ths if i remove that white space dosen t work anymore and it shows just a single dot,and when i click disappears

Comment: I tried to remove it and the clicks on the dots do work as intended, give it a try.

Comment: @ths  I tried your method but when i click on dots nothing happens

Comment: I just figured that you should click on the full dot to go to the other slide.

Comment: @ths woww...yes it works as intended,thanks a lot man,can you help me yo solve it so that when  make when clicking be in the reverse way?

Comment: I'll do my best and I'll post an answer ASAP.

Comment: do you accept some improvements and changes over your current `HTML` and `JavaScript` ?

Comment: @ths if is not another possibility please feel free to change things in code

Comment: the main functionality doesn't require that much functions to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having a lot of functions,, the desired functionality can be done with only few ones.

So let's clarify how things would work :

- the `div.news` are initially hidden.
- the dots (`span.dot` elements) are added on page load by `JavaScript` to be more dynamic thus when adding a new `div.news` (or when the page is created at the backednd) you don't manually have to add a new dot.
- two `data-*` are added into the markup :

  - `data-slideshow-index`: added to `span.dot` elements (done by `JavaScript` as I said above) that holds the index of the `div.news` on which when clicking on the dot that `div.news` will be shown.
  - `data-slideshow-role`: added to `a.cycle` (the last two `a` tags for previous and next functionalities) which defines the role of the `a.cycle` (either *next* or *prev*).
- a function that takes the index of the `div.news` to be shown has the show/hide functionalities (even the class manipulation for the dots).
- a class (`active`) is used to show a slide (`div.news`) so no longer `.style.display` are used.
- technically, no explicit loops are used (no `for` loops in other words), all the looping is done threw the built-in [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) methods.
- also, the events are handled directly in the `JavaScript` part using the [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method.

So let's keep it short, here's a working demo, it also contains a wealth of helpful comments that should assist you when reading (mainly the `JavaScript` part) :

```js
/** 
* news: an array that stores the "div.news" found in the page.
* dotsWrapper: the "div#dots" in where the "span.dot" are going to be added on page load.
* nextPrev: an array that holds the next and prev anchor tags(those with "data-slideshow-role").
* showSlide(idx): the function that does the show/hide for the slides ("div.news").
    @param idx the index of the "div.news" to be shown.
* roles: a plain object that holds two helper functions used by "a.cycle" in order to distinguish which role (show the next or prev slide) based on their "data-slideshow-role" and the index of the "div.news" to be shown.
* dots: an array (populated on page load) that stores the "span.dot" elements.
**/
const news = [...document.querySelectorAll('.news')],
  dotsWrapper = document.getElementById('dots'),
  nextPrev = [...document.querySelectorAll('.cycle')],
  showSlide = idx => {
    /** get the current shown slide **/
    const currVisible = news.find(el => el.classList.contains('visible')),
      /** gets the currently active "span.dot" **/
      currActive = dots.find(d => d.classList.contains('active'));
    /** hide the last shown slide **/
    currVisible && currVisible.classList.remove('visible');
    /** show the slide at the index "idx" **/
    news[idx].classList.add('visible');
    /** remove "active" class from the last active "span.dot" **/
    currActive && currActive.classList.remove('active');
    /** the "span.dot" at the index "idx" becomes active **/
    dots[idx].classList.add('active');
  },
  roles = {
    /** function to do the show next slide role **/
    next: idx => idx === news.length - 1 ? showSlide(0) : showSlide(idx + 1),
    /** function to do the show previous slide role **/
    prev: idx => idx === 0 ? showSlide(news.length - 1) : showSlide(idx - 1)
  }

let dots = null;

(() => {
  /** based on how many "div.news" on the page add a "span.dot" for each one (loop).
  * @param el: the current element in the loop through "div.news" arrays (news array).
  * @param idx its index
  **/
  dotsWrapper.append(...news.map((el, idx) => {
    /** create new "span" element **/
    const newDot = document.createElement('span');
    /** add "dot" class to it **/
    newDot.classList.add('dot');
    /** add data-slideshow-index to it that holds the index of the "div.news" on that dot points **/
    newDot.dataset.slideshowIndex = idx;
    /** add click handler **/
    newDot.addEventListener('click', () => {
      /** if the we click on the currently active dot don't do anything **/
      if(idx == news.find(el => el.classList.contains('visible')).dataset.slideshowIndex) return;
      /** show the "div.news" at the index "idx" **/
      showSlide(idx);
    });
    /** if "idx" = 0 (first "div.news") on the page show it (add "visible class") and add "active" class to the corresponding dot **/
    idx === 0 && (newDot.classList.add('active'), el.classList.add('visible'));
    /** return the created dot **/
    return newDot;
  }));
  /** now the dots are added to the DOM so we can select them to be used while clicking the spans or the anchors **/
  dots = [...dotsWrapper.querySelectorAll('.dot')];
})();

/** 
* loop though the prev and next anchors.
* @pram e the click event object.
**/
nextPrev.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', e => {
    /** revent default click behavior **/
    e.preventDefault();
    /** call the corresponding function on "roles" object based on the role of the clicked "a" element and send to it the index of the currently visible "div.news" element **/
    roles[el.dataset.slideshowRole](news.findIndex(el => el.classList.contains('visible')));
  });
});
```

```css
#section-three .slideshow-container2 .wiew-more:hover {
  color: #242121;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 #dots {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

#section-three .slideshow-container2 .dot:hover,
#section-three .slideshow-container2 .dot.active {
  background: black;
}

.news {
   /** the news div are hidden by default and only the first one in the page will be shown by "JavaScript" **/
  display: none;
}

/** this class is used to show a slide ("div.news") **/
.news.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!-- the "span.dot" are now added by "JavaScript" according to the number of "div.news" on the page -->

<!-- 
added two "data-*" attributes :
  data-slideshow-index: the index of "div.news" which the "span.dot" points to (remember! the "span.dots" are added by "JavaScript").
  data-slideshow-role: the role (can be either "next" or "prev") of the "a.cycle" element (the last two anchor tags).
-->
<section id="section-three">
  <div class="container slideshow-container2">
    <div class="news">
      <div class="news-content">
        <div class="buttons">
          <a class="btn company-btn" href="#">COMPANY NEWS</a>
          <a class="btn industry-btn" href="#">INDUSTRY NEWS</a>
        </div>
        <h1>OUR PEOPLE ARE OUT STONGEST ASSET </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="news news2">
      <div class="news2-content">
        <div class="buttons">
          <a class="btn company-btn" href="#">COMPANY NEWS</a>
          <a class="btn industry-btn" href="#">INDUSTRY NEWS</a>
        </div>
        <h1 class="media-room">MEDIA ROOM </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- the next "div#dots" will be populated by `JavaScript` that adds "span.dot" according to the number of "div.news" in the page -->
    <div id="dots"></div>
    <!-- added "cycle" class (to be used by "JavaScript" for now) and data-slideshow-role attribute -->
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="cycle" data-slideshow-role="prev">prev</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="cycle" data-slideshow-role="next">next</a>
  </div>
</section>
```